# How do I control my mouse with a PS4 controller?

Tags: python, winapi, mouse, joystick, ps4

I wanted to move the mouse cursor with my ps4 controller, so I used pygame and win32api

I came up with this solution to the problem, but it is not working as I intended, because it is extremely laggy

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.JOYAXISMOTION:
        if event.value > self.threshold :
            if event.axis == 2:  
                win32api.SetCursorPos([win32api.GetCursorPos()[0] + self.sensitivity, win32api.GetCursorPos()[1]])
            if event.axis == 3:
                win32api.SetCursorPos([win32api.GetCursorPos()[0], win32api.GetCursorPos()[1] + self.sensitivity])   
        if event.value < -self.threshold :
            if event.axis == 2:  
                win32api.SetCursorPos([win32api.GetCursorPos()[0] - self.sensitivity, win32api.GetCursorPos()[1]])
            if event.axis == 3:
                win32api.SetCursorPos([win32api.GetCursorPos()[0], win32api.GetCursorPos()[1] - self.sensitivity])
```

this just checks if a joystick is in motion, and then translates this movement to the cursor with a given sensitivity by adding that same value to the current position:

```
win32api.SetCursorPos([win32api.GetCursorPos()[0] + self.sensitivity, win32api.GetCursorPos()[1]])
```

Is there any other efficient solution that won't lag my pc?

Comment: GetCursorPos does not return an array.

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm It does not return an array, it returns a tuple with the current x and y position, but I do not get what you mean.

Comment: GetCursorPos returns BOOL and you treat the return value of GetCursorPos like an array.

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm you are thinking of the underlying Win32 API `GetCursorPos()`, which indeed outputs a `POINT` by pointer parameter and returns a `BOOL` for success/failure. But the Python `win32api` module wraps that API to return a tuple containing the coordinates.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the situation better.

Comment: You should probably aim for a solution that reads input using [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) and injects input using [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput). That's both fast and reliable.